# Run a handler play and exit play if rc == 0 in ansible

Tags: ansible

Hi is there a way I can run a handler play then exit the play if rc == 0. It can only do is exit the play using failed_when and proceed if rc != 0. I can't make notify: Service Guard execute. Been play with other approach like creating 2 play notify and exit no luck.

```
- name: Exit SG server from play
  command: /usr/local/cmcluster/bin/cmversion
  register: sg_check
  notify: Service Guard
  failed_when: sg_check.rc == 0
```

Here is new code I tried

```
- name: Check if Service Gurad then exit
  command: /usr/local/cmcluster/bin/cmversion
  register: sg_check
  notify: Service Guard
  changed_when: sg_check.rc == 0
  ignore_errors: true
- meta: end_play
  when: sg_check.rc == 0
```

but I get this:

ERROR! The conditional check 'sg_check.rc == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (sg_check.rc == 0): 'sg_check' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/linuxpatchingv2/roles/applyPatch/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

ignore_errors: true

- meta: end_play
  ^ here

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the "error".

Comment: would be a difference if I'm placing it in a role task?, I think that's why you can't reproduce the error, cause mine is inside a role?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Run a handler play then exit the play if rc == 0"*

A: This is not possible to accomplish in one task because a task can't be both `changed` and `failed` at the same time. These two actions must be split. For example, in the playbook below the command will succeed, notify the handler, and end the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: "{{ cmd|default('/bin/true') }}"
      register: sg_check
      notify: Service Guard
      changed_when: sg_check.rc == 0
      ignore_errors: true
    - meta: end_play
      when: sg_check.rc == 0
    - debug:
        msg: Continue
  handlers:
    - name: Service Guard
      debug:
        msg: Service Guard notified
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
...
RUNNING HANDLER [Service Guard] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Service Guard notified

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

The same playbook will continue if the command fails. For example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "cmd=/bin/false"

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [command] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  cmd:
  - /bin/false
  delta: '0:00:00.003035'
  end: '2020-08-24 09:33:22.039762'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-08-24 09:33:22.036727'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Continue

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=1
```