# How to catch a failure in Ansible and continue the playbook for specific task

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook tat contains (Among other) three specfic tasks.

```
- name: Execute the compilation script
    command: sh {{  working_folder  }}/compile.sh 
    args:
      chdir: "{{  working_folder  }}"
    when:  run_deploy_machine  == "true"

  - name: Execute the deployment script
    command: sh {{  working_folder  }}/deploy.sh 
    args:
      chdir: "{{  working_folder  }}"
    when:  run_deploy_machine  == "true"
 
  - name: Start the JBoss server
    shell: . /jboss start
```

THe problem is that if any of the first two tasks fails, I need (As part of the failure process) activate the logic of the last task (It might be as a handler).
I saw that there is the block/rescue option, the problem is that if I use it- the rescue "cancel" the failure.
All I need is that in case of the failure- to execute the start JBoss, but that the playbook will still fail.

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: See how to use [handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555584/run-a-handler-play-and-exit-play-if-rc-0-in-ansible/63556841#63556841).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use a block/rescue and use a fail task at the end of the rescue tasks. Here is a global idea:

```yaml
---
- name: Clean fail in rescue demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - block:

        - name: task that may fail
          command: /bin/false

        - name: other task that might fail
          command: /does/this/work

      rescue:

        - name: task to remedy fail
          command: echo remedy

        - name: cleanly fail the host anyway
          fail:
            msg: clean fail after remedy
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```yaml
  - name: Execute the compilation script
    command: sh {{  working_folder  }}/compile.sh 
    args:
      chdir: "{{  working_folder  }}"
    when:  run_deploy_machine  == "true"
    register: a
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Execute the deployment script
    command: sh {{  working_folder  }}/deploy.sh 
    args:
      chdir: "{{  working_folder  }}"
    when:  run_deploy_machine  == "true"
    register: b
    ignore_errors: True
 
  - name: Start the JBoss server
    shell: . /jboss start
    when: a.rc != "0" or b.rc != "0"

  - name: fail if build or deploy failed
    fail:
      msg: "Build or deploy failed!"
    when: a.rc != "0" or b.rc != "0"
```

You register the variables `a` and `b` to contain the output of the commands. `rc` will contain the exit code, so if that is not `0` the command failed.
If one of those commands failed, you execute task no. 3 and then fail.
`ignore_errors: True` prevents the play to fail instantly if one of the first steps fail.

Documentation:
[shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html)
[error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)
[fail](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html)

Comment: Hi, I thought of using it first, but the problem is that if the compilation phase fails, I don't want to continue to the deployment stage, I could have still check after every stage if it failed and then run the JBoss, but it would have been little complicated

Comment: So do you want to run the JBoss in any case, regardless of what fails before?

Comment: Yes, but only the JBoss, if the compile fails- I just want the JBoss to start, without performing what comes after the compile